# ACF WP_Query Filter by Taxonomy Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to filter a CPT to display fields by Taxonomy, I am currently using the following code:-

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_type'     => 'episode',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    //'meta_key'        =>  $filter_key,
    //'meta_value'  =>  $filter,                                
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'name',
            'field' => 'make',
            'terms' => array('Jaguar')
        )
    ),  
);
```

However, this is not returning any results.

This is what I am trying to filter:-

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#7336 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(25) ["name"]=> string(6) "Jaguar" ["slug"]=> string(6) "jaguar" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(25) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(0) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [1]=> object(WP_Term)#7493 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(24) ["name"]=> string(13) "Mercedes K100" ["slug"]=> string(13) "mercedes-k100" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(24) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(0) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [2]=> object(WP_Term)#7492 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(26) ["name"]=> string(10) "Porche 911" ["slug"]=> string(10) "porche-911" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(26) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(0) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } } array(3) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#7503 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(25) ["name"]=> string(6) "Jaguar" ["slug"]=> string(6) "jaguar" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(25) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(0) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [1]=> object(WP_Term)#7490 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(24) ["name"]=> string(13) "Mercedes K100" ["slug"]=> string(13) "mercedes-k100" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(24) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(0) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } [2]=> object(WP_Term)#7489 (10) { ["term_id"]=> int(26) ["name"]=> string(10) "Porche 911" ["slug"]=> string(10) "porche-911" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(26) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "post_tag" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(0) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" } }
```

So the name of my taxonomy field is called 'make' and for test purposes I just want to display all the posts that have a Taxonomy of 'Jaguar'

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to sort this in the end, @mrben522 was quite right that the args should be as follows:-

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_type'     => 'episode',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms' => array('Jaguar'),
            'field' => 'name',              
        )
    ),
    'order'             => 'DESC',                                    
);
```

However, this alone didn't resolve the issue. What I also had to do is change the option for the Taxonomy field within ACF. The 'Save Terms' option was set to 'No' but changing this option to 'Yes' got this working for me.

[image]

If you are using the 'Save Terms' setting in the taxonomy field, the selected terms will be saved as connections between the post and the term - just like WP core. This means that all the code will work with or without ACF.

Posting this solution as it may be helpful to someone else, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
array(
            'taxonomy' => 'name',
            'field' => 'make',
            'terms' => array('Jaguar')
        )
```

is wrong.  should be

```
array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => array('Jaguar')
        )
```

Check out the docs on [WP Query taxonomy parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for info on how that works

EDIT:  looking at the var dump you posted is appears that Jaguar is a post tag, not a custom taxonomy called 'make'

Comment: Thanks @mrben522 - I tried with the above code but it's still returning nothing, any ideas?

Comment: The var_dump is of `get_field('make');` - which is the ACF Taxonomy field (which is using Taxonomy; Tag)

Comment: OHHHH now I get it.  you can't use ACF like that.  if you're trying to filter things by an ACF field in a query you need to use a meta query, not a tax query

Comment: I'm not really sure what the end goal is here